# Saving vectors in a Mat opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to save 4 Matrix inside a Matrix.But I was not sure if we can do that.So I converted my 4matrix to 4 vectors. Now I want to insert the 4 vectors in the matrix. My code is:

```
       Mat hist_TL = Mat::zeros(20,1, CV_32F);
       Mat hist_TR = Mat::zeros(20,1, CV_32F);
       Mat hist_BL = Mat::zeros(20,1, CV_32F);
       Mat hist_BR = Mat::zeros(20,1, CV_32F);
        for(int i=1;i<=21;i++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<TL_k_stats.rows;k++)
            {
            if((angl_TL<=bins[i]) && (angl_TL>bins[i-1]))
            {
               hist_TL.at<float>(i-1,0)+=TL_k_stats.at<float>(k,4);
            }
            if((angl_TR<=bins[i]) && (angl_TR>bins[i-1]))
               {
                hist_TR.at<float>(i-1,0)+=TR_k_stats.at<float>(k,4);
               }

            if((angl_BL<=bins[i]) && (angl_BL>bins[i-1]))
               {
                hist_BL.at<float>(i-1,0)+=BL_k_stats.at<float>(k,4);
               }

            if((angl_BR<=bins[i]) && (angl_BR>bins[i-1]))
               {
                hist_BR.at<float>(i-1,0)+=BR_k_stats.at<float>(k,4);
               }
            }
        hist_TL=hist_TL.inv();
        hist_TR=hist_TR.inv();
        hist_BL=hist_BL.inv();
        hist_BR=hist_BR.inv();
        std::vector<float> vhist_TL;
        std::vector<float> vhist_TR;
        std::vector<float> vhist_BL;
        std::vector<float> vhist_BR;

        hist_TL.copyTo(vhist_TL);
        hist_TR.copyTo(vhist_TR);
        hist_BL.copyTo(vhist_BL);
        hist_BR.copyTo(vhist_BR);
```

So I want to copy the the 4 vectors to one Matrix. If there is any way i can do it without the conversion of matrix to vector.Please let me know.In matlab we can directly store it into an array and return it like this

```
features[] = {hist_TL', hist_TR', hist_BL', hist_BR'};
```

So how can I achieve this in opencv??

Answer (score 0):

You could utilise the 'col' methods that allow you to assign values to the columns individually:

```
   Mat hist_TL = Mat::zeros(20,1, CV_32F)+1;
   Mat hist_TR = Mat::zeros(20,1, CV_32F)+2;
   Mat hist_BL = Mat::zeros(20,1, CV_32F)+3;
   Mat hist_BR = Mat::zeros(20,1, CV_32F)+4;

   Mat result = Mat::zeros(20,4,CV_32F);

   hist_TL.col(0).copyTo(result.col(0));
   hist_TR.col(0).copyTo(result.col(1));
   hist_BL.col(0).copyTo(result.col(2));
   hist_BR.col(0).copyTo(result.col(3));
```

**UPDATE:**

If you do not want to replace whole columns, but just parts of them, you can use the 'Range' methods:

```
   Mat result = Mat::zeros(20*4,1,CV_32F);

   hist_TL.copyTo(result.rowRange(Range(20*0,20*1)));
   hist_TR.copyTo(result.rowRange(Range(20*1,20*2)));
   hist_BL.copyTo(result.rowRange(Range(20*2,20*3)));
   hist_BR.copyTo(result.rowRange(Range(20*3,20*4)));
```

Comment: But I have to transpose the Mat hist_TL and others before saving it.So that it will have a single row with munltiple columns

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the 4 matrix into a larger one directly like this:

```
    Mat TL(rows, cols, type);
    Mat TR(rows, cols, type);
    Mat BL(rows, cols, type);
    Mat BR(rows, cols, type);
    Mat dst(rows * 2, cols *2, type);
    TL.copyTo(dst(Rect(0, 0, cols, rows)));
    TR.copyTo(dst(Rect(cols, 0, cols, rows)));
    BL.copyTo(dst(Rect(0, rows, cols, rows)));
    BR.copyTo(dst(Rect(cols, rows, cols, rows)));
```

The documents:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#rect
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=copyto#mat-copyto